# if I create a child class from within a parent class, the parent class gets created again the Java

Tags: java, class

```
public class Map
{
    public Map()
    {
    }

    int[][] Map = {{0,0,0,0,0},
                   {0,0,0,0,0},
                   {0,0,0,0,0}};
}

public class Unit extends Map
{
    int x, y, num;

    public Unit(int x, int y, int num)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.num = num;
    }

    public void Set()
    {
        super.Map[x][y] = num;
    }
}

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Unit a = new Unit(1,1,5);
        a.Set();
        Unit b = new Unit(2,2,10);
        b.Set();
    }
}
```

If you run this code, a.Map and b.Map are made separately. I wish a parent and a b would like to participate together. Is there any way?
By default, when you make new classes from different classes of class, are the parent classes made as many as that number?

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question. Your question is not very clear - the last paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

`Unit` doesn't seem like a natural sub-class of `Map`. Before you write `class Unit extends Map` you should be asking yourself whether a `Unit` is a kind of a `Map`. I don't think it is.

If you want to have multiple `Unit`s on a single `Map`, create a single `Map` instance, and add each `Unit` instance you create to that `Map`.

Here's a partial example:

```
public class Map {
    int[][] map = {{0,0,0,0,0},
                   {0,0,0,0,0},
                   {0,0,0,0,0}};
    public setUnit (Unit unit) {
        map[unit.getX()][unit.getY()] = unit.getNum();
    }
}

public class Unit
{
    int x, y, num;

    public Unit(int x, int y, int num)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.num = num;
    }
}

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Map m = new Map ();
        Unit a = new Unit(1,1,5);
        map.setUnit(a);
        Unit b = new Unit(2,2,10);
        map.setUnit(b);
    }
}
```

If the `Unit` objects need access to the `Map` that contains them, you can consider adding a `Map map` instance variable to the `Unit` class.

Comment: Thanks to the kind answers, my problem is resolved. I need to learn more about Java inheritance and objects. Thank you.